# django forms fields of a form in a single line

Tags: django, forms

i have a form which is like

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from OEConnector import *

class Personal_info_updateForm(forms.Form):
    title_choices = ( ('herr', 'Herr'), ('frau', 'Frau'))
    #Dates tuple list
    dates=[]
    for x in range(1,32):        
        dates.append(tuple([x.__str__(),x.__str__()]))        
    dates = tuple(dates)
    #Months tuple list
    months = (
          ('jan','Januar'),
          ('feb','Februar'),
          ('mar','Marz'),
          ('apr','April'),
          ('may','Mai'),
          ('jun','Juni'),
          ('jul','Juli'),
          ('aug','August'),
          ('sep','September'),
          ('oct','Oktober'),
          ('nov','November'),
          ('dec','Dezember'),
          )
    #Years tuple list
    years=[('','')]
    for y in range(1930,2050):        
        years.append(tuple([y.__str__(),y.__str__()]))        
    years = tuple(years)
    #Get list of countries from OpenERP and create countries tuple list

    title = forms.ChoiceField(label="Anrede", choices=title_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="Vorname", required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Nachname", required=False)
    date_of_birth = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dates, widget=forms.Select, required=False)
    month_of_birth = forms.ChoiceField(choices=months, widget=forms.Select, required=False)
    year_of_birth = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years, widget=forms.Select, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email',required=False)
    phone = forms.CharField(label="Phone", required=False)
    mobile = forms.CharField(label="Mobile", required=False)
```

i am calling this form in my template.It shows me like
Date of birth:
Month of birth: 
Year of birth:

Now i want that these three fields come in a single line like
Date of birth:     Month of birth:      Year of birth:

My template is like

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <table style="color:black;text-align:left; margin-left: 20px;">
        {{ form.as_table }}

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="UPDATE">
</form>
```

I want like 
Date of birth:     Month of birth:      Year of birth:

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

rather then splitting the field you could use a DateField with the [SelectDateField](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/extras/widgets.py#L16) widget e.g.

```
forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=[y for y in range(1930,2050)]))
```

this would display as one row in the form - [month][day][year]

Comment: I agree with @JamesO, your best bet would be to user a SelectDateWidget, then you can do some extra formatting on that if you please.